# spark-xml with gzip input files

Tags: xml, apache-spark, gzip

when i'm trying to load gzipped xml files with spark-xml input format I always get an empty dataframe back. When loading gzip files with text input format it is all working fine. Am I doing anything wrong or is this just not supported for spark-xml?

```
val books = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag","catalog")
    .option("rowTag","book")
    .load("/data/books.xml.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was using an old version. Everything is working fine with version 0.3.3